# How to get process ID and cpu core of the subprocess module in python

Tags: python, linux, unix, subprocess

I am writing python code which will use subprocess and its method check_output, I am also calling  with threading to take multi core advantage, (Assuming calling subprocess with threading uses multicore)

Now what i have to print is, subprocess output, process ID, CPU core is used to execule sleep command in OS
Example:

```
  result = subprocess.check_output(["sleep", "5"])
  print(result)
  print("Process ID: ", os.getpid()) # This is wrong i guess, because in OS subprocess used different process ID and CPU, If this is wrong, How to get PID of subprocess
  print("CPU Core used: ") # This also required help to print
```